# Showing Push notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I set my application for push notification and all is running fine. But i want that push notification should also show when my application is running. I do-not want to show an alert or pop in my application

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built-in to iOS that will make push notification popup appears if the app for the notification is currently in the foreground. You need to look at the data you get in the notification and create a `UIAlertView` by hand.

Comment: If you don't want to show an alert, you'll have to make your own custom UI to display the notification. I don't think there's a way to  show the iOS 5 flip animation while in your app.